# C constants throwing compile-time errors

Tags: c, compiler-errors, constants

Several people have commented on my C code here, saying that I should use constants as loop counters, rather than hard-writing them.  I agree with them, since that is my practice when writing Java code, but I'm having compile-time errors thrown when I try to use constants in array declarations and loop conditionals.

To declare a constant in C, the syntax is `#define NAME value`.

In my code, I have two constants,`BUFFER` is the file read buffer, and `PACKED` is the output array size.

I use `BUFFER` to initialize `char inputBuffer[BUFFER];` as a global variable, which works, but when I try to use `PACKED`

```
#define PACKED    7; // this line is in the header of file, just below preprocessors
int packedCount;
char inputPack[PACKED]; //compression storage
for (packedCount=0; packedCount<= PACKED; packedCount++){
```

I get am  `error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token` at `char inputPack[PACKED]` AND
 `error: expected expression before ‘;’ token` in the loop initialization line.  Both errors disappear when I replace `PACKED` with 7.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at the end of `char inputPack[PACKED]`

Comment: Just as Marlon said. Is it a typo here?

Comment: Please paste exactly the code you compile

Comment: You don't get a C constant with a #define, it's just a literal text. The C language has a const keyword, that tell the compiler that a variable must not be changed.

Comment: @Marlon, that's just a typo.  I copied the appropriate lines referring to the problem here, turns out I didn't copy the whole thing.  The problem was a semicolon in the `#define` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously are not posting the code exactly as it appears in your source file.

At the very least, you are missing the semicolon after `char inputPack[PACKED]`.

I strongly suspect that your real source has a semicolon at the end of your macro declaration, which would cause the error. Macro definitions should not be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: +1 for `you included a semicolon at the end of your macro declaration`

Comment: That was it.  I think it'll be a while before I separate C syntax from the matching Java syntax.

Answer (score 2):

there is a `;` missing after char `inputPack[PACKED]`

Answer (score 1):

Try using something other than PACKED, e.g. PACKEDSIZE. It *could* be that your compiler uses PACKED for something else (e.g. related to struct packing). Also, as other answers mention, you're lacking a ;

Comment: Macro's with capital letters aren't reserved by the implementation. They need to begin with underscores as well. I don't remember the actual ruling (it differs between C and c++), but `PACKED` shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: Shouldn't and won't are unfortunately not always correlating :) - But, Jonathan spotted the real problem I believe.